# GeoServer doesnt seed all vector tiles

Tags: geoserver, vector-tiles, wmts

When I open my layer using the preview tool (OpenLayers) .. The data folder gets populated with the correct PBF tiles. However when I use the Seed tool I get less tiles for the same zoom level. How can I fix that?

[image]

Geoserver log - https://www.file.io/x1mf/download/5Agtq4Fkx2Ug

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: I added geoserver log to the question .. One more thing .. If I seed PNG instead of PBF for the same gridset and zoom level it generates the expected tiles.

Comment: you need to find the relevant error message in the log file and extract that into your question, not provide some mystery link that no one is going to click on.

Comment: There are no ERROR messages in the log .. There are warnings ,however I am not Geoserver savy to undestand whats happening ,otherwise I wouldnt be asking questions here

Comment: what is in the log when you request just that tile?

Comment: `19 Feb 14:02:29 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] "GET /geoserver/sofia/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=GetTile&SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0&LAYER=sofia:planet_osm_line&STYLE=&TILEMATRIX=EPSG:900913:18&TILEMATRIXSET=EPSG:900913&FORMAT=application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile&TILECOL=148055&TILEROW=96652"`

Comment: So it's working? Try turning up the log level